# Puzzle #111731267 - 19 Crossed Pairs

Tags: word, knowledge, pattern, crosswords

**Instructions:**
There are 19 pairs of related answers with a common theme. Each pair consists of an across answer and a down answer. These two answers cross at a single letter marked with a number.
All 19 pairs are related in a similar way.
Each numbered clue is for one of the crossed answers, either across or down. You will need to determine the other answer.
The final answer to the puzzle is 19 letters long.

[image: crossword]

> 1. Big name in U.S. sports equipment
> 2. LOTR film director
> 3. King of England in 1603
> 4. Dunder Mifflin salesman
> 5. Swiss folk hero
> 6. First U.S. postmaster general
> 7. Curious monkey
> 8. Fictional king of England
> 9. Small city in Kentucky
> 10. Portwenn doctor
> 11. Doubting disciple

> … etc.

> 16. U.S. vacuum brand
> 17. Big U.S. auto maker
> 18. McDonald’s clown
> 19. Singer Swift

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, let's find one answer to each given clue

> 1. WILSON
>  2. JACKSON
>  3. JAMES
>  4. DWIGHT (Schrute)
>  5. WILLIAM (Tell)
>  6. BENJAMIN (Franklin)
>  7. GEORGE
>  8. ARTHUR
>  9. LYNDON
>  10. MARTIN
>  11. THOMAS
>  16. HOOVER
>  17. FORD
>  18. RONALD
>  19. TAYLOR

Now notice that

> Each of these answers is either the first or last name of a former U.S. president and the other name gives the other answer for the same clue. In particular, for the above the two answers are
>  1. WOODROW WILSON
>  2. ANDREW JACKSON
>  3. JAMES MADISON
>  4. DWIGHT EISENHOWER
>  5. WILLIAM MCKINLEY
>  6. BENJAMIN HARRISON
>  7. GEORGE WASHINGTON
>  8. CHESTER ARTHUR
>  9. LYNDON JOHNSON
>  10. MARTIN VANBUREN
>  11. THOMAS JEFFERSON
>  16. HERBERT HOOVER
>  17. GERALD FORD
>  18. RONALD REAGAN
>  19. ZACHARY TAYLOR

We can then deduce the unclued answers using the grid

> 12. BARACK OBAMA
>  13. MILLARD FILLMORE
>  14. WARREN HARDING
>  15. THEODORE ROOSEVELT

To complete the grid like this

> [image]

The 19 highlighted letters spell out

> WASHINGTONS BIRTHDAY

which is

> 22nd February 1732

However this is also

> A holiday also known as **Presidents' Day** and is celebrated this year on **20 February, 2023** (today, at the time of posting).